# internal server error (500) in development mode, no debug page or log output in rails: utf-8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, utf-8, ruby-1.9

rails app in development mode gives internal server error and not the usual error page with trace. no info in `log/development.log` either. no matter what server. on any request.

What is wrong?

Comment: look at the server's error log. if it's a 500, it could be killing things before ruby even has a chance to get involved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

syntax error caused by invalid character coding under ruby 1.9. most likely you used utf-8 when ruby (and rails) expects ASCII by default in source files. (yeah, right?)

solution is to use BOM http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-byte-order-mark or put

```
# encoding: UTF-8
```

or

```
# coding: UTF-8
```

on top of files in utf-8.

To set `UTF-8` globally, you can put

```
config.encoding = "utf-8"
```

in your `config/application.rb` which is equivalent to

```
Encoding.default_external = Encoding::UTF_8
Encoding.default_internal = Encoding::UTF_8
```

which in turn is the equivalent to putting:

```
# encoding: UTF-8
```

or a BOM at the top of every file.

This allows utf-8 globally on all files of the rails app.

If you want a global option on all ruby files, you can use the `-E` or `-K` ruby option and set it via the `RUBYOPT` environment variable, like:

```
export RUBYOPT=-Ku
```

or

```
export RUBYOPT='-E utf-8:utf-8'
```

see http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/ruby/
see http://zargony.com/2009/07/24/ruby-1-9-and-file-encodings

There's also gem that sets the magic comment on top on every file that needs it in a Rails project : h[ttps://github.com/m-ryan/magic_encoding](https://github.com/m-ryan/magic_encoding)